# MediaElement.js - video opens in a new tab on mac/FF17

Tags: javascript, mediaelement.js

I am doing maintenance on an app that uses mediaelement.js. the players works fine on mac/chrome, pc/ie8, pc/ff17, but on mac/ff17, the video opens in a new tab and plays there.

I am not very expericed with mac, but my browser has a fresh flash plugin, and I checked the file extension associations and and it is all set on quicktime.

Is the opening in a new tab a fallback behavior ? Thats my guess : if the player cant be started for some reason, then mediaelement.js tries to make the browser download the file, and because of the file association, quicktime plays it within a new tab.

I have this behavior on the tested site, but on mediaelementjs.com the example video plays well on mac/ff17. Would that be due to a different type(file extension) of the video ?

Comment: It might be due to a different file extension, but it's important to note when talking about video (especially in browsers) the **codecs** used for audio and video.

Comment: Yes, but I m not sure how to answer. The video used comes from the mediaelementjs.com website. Dunno if there is a way to retrieve the list of codecs that a browser is able to use.

Comment: Try downloading the video from that website and using a tool like `ffmpeg` to figure out the codecs used, and compare them to the video causing you trouble. `ffmpeg -i` might return something like `Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High)...Stream #0:1(dut): Audio: aac`